# return all data with some special case sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Help, I have query that return this

```
id user_id host_id data is_accepted
1     2       1    lorem     true
2     3       1    ipsum     true
3     4       1    dolor     false
7     1       1    amet      false
```

My question how can i return only id 1,2,7 (
the point is i want return all data related to the host but the is_accepted = 0 is for only specific user)

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please *do not* post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data.

Comment: @Stu thank you for reminding me, i do not know the question guide, im new here

Comment: @Stu yeah but i rarely use stackoverflow, i dont know if there is a question guide, bcs all this time i only directly ask something if i need anything

Comment: What does `is_accepted` have to do with this?

Comment: What is the query that returns this? Your original screenshot had a query, why didn't you include that when you converted to text?

Comment: @JEPPUNG look at the replies and comment on them if they're not working. Regarding the "is_accepted" part, do you need help with that? If so, please include an example.

Comment: @Barmar its just like after posting data, i want have a verification first then if it pass the verification it become true

Answer (score 0):

You can use WHERE to filter out data (1,2,7) and you can use AND to join them together

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use where in to do this.
Fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6aSWwcyVb5usq2BW4Urdc3/0

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  user_id int,
  host_id int,
  data varchar(50),
  is_accepted int
);
INSERT INTO test (id, user_id, host_id, data, is_accepted) 
VALUES 
(1,2,1,'lorem', 1),
(2,3,1,'ipsum', 1),
(3,4,1,'dolor', 0),
(7,1,1,'amet', 0);

SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE test.id in (1,2,7)
```

Result:

| id | user_id | host_id | data | is_accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | lorem | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | ipsum | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | amet | 0 |

Then, obviously you can add other things such as "And( (user_id = 2 and is_accepted = true) or (user_id != 2)) to accept ALL users regardless of is_accepted, except for user_id 2 which has to be is_accepted as true.

Example of this in this fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6aSWwcyVb5usq2BW4Urdc3/2

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  user_id int,
  host_id int,
  data varchar(50),
  is_accepted int
);
INSERT INTO test (id, user_id, host_id, data, is_accepted) 
VALUES 
(1,2,1,'lorem', 1),
(2,3,1,'ipsum', 1),
(3,4,1,'dolor', 0),
(7,1,1,'amet', 0);

SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE test.id in (1,2,7)
And( (test.user_id = 1 and test.is_accepted = 1) or (test.user_id != 1))
```

Result:

| id | user_id | host_id | data | is_accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | lorem | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | ipsum | 1 |